# Some specific Akka questions

Tags: websocket, akka, akka-http

I am currently looking into akka for a project of mine. I want to build a webserver that mainly communicates on websockets (its for collecting multiple (say thousands) streams of data of about 1-5gb an hour).

This is going to be a project that needs horizontal scaling and what I want to do is basically accept a http request but start a remote actor (probably on a different machine) to upgrade the connection to a websocket connection. Is this possible with Akka(-http)? My current knowledge says it shouldnt be possible but I am not certain.

Also... when I write my actor system in scala, can I start actors written with akka in C#.net and the other way around?